# How to use a Keras trained Embedded layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word-embedding

My model is:

```
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                            output_dim=1024, input_length=self.SEQ_LENGTH))

        model.add(LSTM(vocab_size))

        model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
        model.add(Dense(vocab_size - 1, activation='softmax'))
```

And I have it trained. But now during inference time, how can I use that embedding?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Could you elaborate by what you mean with "use"? If you have trained the model, then during inference time you pass the same type of data through the `.predict` function.

Comment: I think you might get some help from here (https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/)

Comment: Your question is solved here [https://github.com/javaidnabi31/Word-Embeddding-Sentiment-Classification/blob/master/lstm-gru-sentiment-analysis.ipynb]

Comment: @AlvaroRomeroDiaz if you post an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is solved [here](https://github.com/javaidnabi31/Word-Embeddding-Sentiment-Classification/blob/master/lstm-gru-sentiment-analysis.ipynb). As skeleton you can use this code:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

tokenizer_obj = Tokenizer()
tokenizer_obj.fit_on_texts(your_dataset) 

...

max_length = max_number_words
X_test_tokens = tokenizer_obj.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
X_test_pad = pad_sequences(X_test_tokens, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test_pad, y_test, batch_size=128)
```